# wildfly10 - filter multiple values

Tags: filter, wildfly-10

i want to filter my wildfly10 logfile.

I get error messages like this:

```
28 Feb 2019 11:22:43,906 ERROR [com.ser.sedna.services.transfer.xf.util.InvocationContextImpl] (default task-6) Exception caught in webservice method.: SECU0015I: The caller **** does not have the abacRead permission on...
```

My configuration looks like this:

```
        <size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;WFLYEJB0043|SECU0015I|abacRead&quot;))"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file path="*****/server.log"/>
            <rotate-size value="15M"/>
            <max-backup-index value="10"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </size-rotating-file-handler>
```

The filter i set does not work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart the server after editing the XML?

Comment: Yes, after editing the xml i made a restart with: jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:reload

Comment: I also tried <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;SECU0015I&quot;))"/> and <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;abacRead&quot;))"/> - but the error still appears.

Comment: I just tested with a different match and it worked. Could you try the CLI command `/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:write-attribute(name=filter-spec, value="not(match(\"WFLYEJB0043|SECU0015I|abacRead\"))")`

Comment: Maybe there was a bug there in WildFly 10. You could try `value=not(match("WFLYEJB0043|SECU0015I|abacRead"))` which _may_ work.

Comment: That's really weird. The only files that should be getting written would be the `logging.properties` and the `standalone.xml`.

Comment: Sorry, i am a total noob :-( I forgot to connect to the jboss cli via `./bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=localhost` Now the command works. I will try the filtering again

Comment: Filter still does not work :-(

Comment: Interesting. It was definitely working for me, but I was testing on WildFly 16. Though I'd think it should work fine on 10.